# How to know if site has index of mode enabled in Python?

Tags: html, python-requests

I've been wondering if there is any way to send a request to the site to determine if the site has 'index of' mode enabled; by that, I mean the site has all of the directories indexed (or part of visible directories).
Is there any way I could do it using HTTP requests in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The closest you could come would be to make requests to URLs on the site that ended in `/` and then run some heuristics to see if the format of the HTML document that came back matched the automatically generated index pages of various common web servers.